# Is there a formatter for scanf that allows me to ignore spaces until the next string, which I needs to read spaces? C language

Tags: c, string, scanf, ansi-c

Doing a poject for uni,

Facing a problem where I need to read a line where I need to read the first char to choose the command (used a getchar, works fine). The first char is separated by an undetermined amount of `' '` until a string is input. The string itself needs to be able to read until the end of the line (including `' '`).

Would this work?

```
char c;
c= getchar();
while(c==' ')
  c=getchar();
```

or would the last `c` get "eaten"? then I would need to add it manually to the string, right?

As a follow up, if I did after:

```
string[0]=c;
scanf("%20[^\n]", string);
```

would I overwrite the first character?

Comment: `man ungetc`.  The problem of a final char getting "eaten" is a well-known issue.

Comment: To quote the `scanf` documentation: `most conversions skip white space`.  IOW, don't even worry about it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function, paragraph 8 says "Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless
the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier.". Here `[` specifier, which doesn't skip white-space characters, is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

```
string[0]=c;
scanf("%20[^\n]", string);
```

will overwrite the first character.

You can add a whitespace character to the format specifier to tell `scanf()` ignore whitespace characters.

```
scanf(" %20[^\n]", string);
```

If you want to skip whitespace characters manually, you can use [`ungetc()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3p.html) to put the first wanted character back to the stream

```
ungetc(c, stdin);
scanf("%20[^\n]", string);
```

or manually put the character to the array, then have `scanf()` store what is read after the first element.

```
string[0]=c;
scanf("%20[^\n]", string + 1);
```

Comment: does `scanf(" %20[^\n]", string)` ignore all whitespaces or just one?

Comment: It will ignore all whitespaces before first non-whitespace character.